# Authenticating with a form when using <authetication mode="None"/> in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, azure-active-directory

I'm implementing Azure AD SSO with OpenID Connect into my ASP.NET MVC application which works as excepted when signing in. However, if a user that does not have an account in the specified AD and has to sign in with a username and password using a form, it fails.

I'm setting up a form this way:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "Authetication"))
```

On sumbit, the controller method is firing, and the database checks are done and sets up a sign in user with all custom global variables needed. The problem is then when redirecting to the account start page after signing in

```
Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
```

When signing in with Azure AD, the redirection works fine, but when signing in with a username and password, the global variables, the session variables and the context variables needed are emptied and set to null.

How do I solve this?

I'm using .NET 4.5, I've followed the MS documentation and the Form authentication has worked prior to adding Azure AD, however, the authentication mode was set to Forms.